# Effectiveness of Belarc Advisor

Tags: windows, hardening, iis

I have seen some people recommend [Belarc Advisor](http://www.belarc.com/free_download.html) for Windows hardening, especially for servers. It's supposed to check for stuff such as installed hotfixes and CIS benchmarks (<-- which are great, btw).

So question is: Anybody tried it? Anybody know something better?
Hypothetical situation I'm in is that I'm an engineer in development and I need to make it as easy as possible for the IT guys to manage our servers since they don't have the best grip on security.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very subjective question - as you will see from the [FAQ](https://security.stackexchange.com/faq), subjective questions will usually be closed.

In saying that, I would say that while I think Belarc may be useful for a home PC, it really isn't the sort of thing I would ever use in an enterprise or SME environment, nor have I ever seen it used outside the home.

I would recommend looking for a product which can tie in with your policies, central exception logging and centrally managed - there are a lot on the market, depending on your price range.

Comment: I only know Belarc for one thing, indirectly giving free licence keys to everyone, try it yourself in Google: `intitle:"Belarc Advisor Current Profile" "Windows XP Professional" key`

I know those people uploaded the files themselves but I find it very dangerous for them to have included licence keys in their reports.